# Sane solution for an ODE with physical interpretation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have an object which is being subjected to a continual force that is a quadratic function of the object's velocity, ie, $F=f_0+f_1 v + f_2 v^2$ for arbitrary but given constants $f_0$, $f_1$, and $f_2$, where $f_2$ is non-zero.

Assuming that $v$ is a function of $t$, and plugging in Newton's second law, $F=ma$, we get:

$$F=f_0+f_1 v(t) + f_2 v(t)^2 = m v'(t)$$

If the object's initial velocity is $v(0)=v_0$, I used wolfram's ODE solver to get the result:

$$
 \begin {array}{c} 
v(t) = \frac{ \sqrt {4f_{{0}}f_{{2}}-{f_{{1}}}^{2}} \tan \left( \frac{ c+ \sqrt {4f_{{0}}f_{{2}}-{f_{{1}}}^{2}} t  }{2 m} \right) -f_{{1}} }{2 f_{{2}}} \\ 
c = 2m \arctan \left( {\frac {f_{{1}}  +2f_{{2}}v_{{0}}}{ \sqrt{4f_{{0}}f_{{2}}-{f_{{1}}}^{2}}}} \right) 
\end {array}
$$

However, solving it in this way, it appears to have both singularities as well as complex solutions, depending on the values of $f_0$, $f_1$, and $f_2$, which of course is not possible as this is supposed to be a representation of a physical process.

So... how do I actually solve this?

Edit:

For clarification, the constants $f_0$, $f_1$, and $f_2$ do genuinly represent real phenomena.... $f_0$ representing any constant force that may be applied, such as gravity, $f_1$ representing Stokes' drag, and $f_2$ representing Newtonian drag.  We can assume that it will never be the case that $f_1$ or $f_2$ will have the same sign as the velocity.  For these purposes, we can assume that Newtownian drag will always be present.

And so I would say that my biggest problem I an having with this is that because other than the qualifications mentioned above, the constants $f_0$, $f_1$, and $f_2$ can potentially be arbitrary reals, and either positive or negative, it is quite easy to contrive a case where $4f_0 f_2 \le {f_1}^2$, for example, if there is a very small Stokes' drag, or if the constant force being applied to the object opposes the newtonian drag, making $f_0 f_2$ negative.  This makes $\sqrt{4f_0 f_2 - {f_1}^2}$ complex, and I am sincerely hoping to avoid having to resort to complex arithmetic if it is at all possible... Even a piecewise solution would be preferable, but I don't know how to find solutions for all cases.  In particular, I don't know how the formula for $v(t)$ would need to be altered when $\sqrt{4f_0 f_2 - {f_1}^2}$ is complex so that complex arithmetic can be avoided.

The singular case where $4f_0 f_2 = {f_1}^2$, as long as $f_1 + 2f_2 v_0 \ne 0$ could theoretically be handled as one such special case, since I am taking the $\arctan$ of the latter over the former, $c$ will nicely work out to be be $\pm 2m\pi$ in such cases, as Narasimham noted below.  The sign of $c$ in such aa case would depend only on the sign of $f_1 + 2f_2 v_0$.  However, if $f_1 + 2f_2 v_0=0$, then $\frac{f_1 + 2f_2 v_0=0}{\sqrt{4f_0 f_2 = {f_1}^2}} = \frac{0}{0}$, which is undefined, so I would need yet another special case to handle that scenario.

Comment: You can't avoid singularities, because any solution to $v'=v^2$ with $v$ initially positive goes to infinity in finite time. Your "physical process" is not physically realizable.

Comment: Ah, for Newtonian drag you should have $mv'=f_0-f_1v-f_2v|v|$ instead with $f_1\ge0,f_2\ge0$, so that the drag forces always oppose the instantaneous velocity. Perhaps this clarifies things: when $v(0)$ and $f_0$ have opposite signs, the solution will appear to have a finite-time singularity, but as soon as it crosses zero it will switch to another analytical form where it asymptotically approaches a terminal velocity. As for your complex-valued solution though, I don't know; you might have to follow Julián's advice and consider the cases carefully.

Comment: Stokes(-ian) drag and Newtonian drag are both *approximations*; each is meant only to model drag accurately for small velocities, or under other hypotheses.  Thus, it is doubtful whether such equations should be regarded as being physically realistic for all velocities.

Answer (score 1):

It is a separable equation:
$$
\frac{m\,v'}{f_0+f_1\,v+f_2\,v^2}=1.
$$
The solution is
$$
\int_0^{v_0}\frac{m\,dv}{f_0+f_1\,v+f_2\,v^2}=t.
$$

Comment: What happened to the factor of $m$ in your integral?

Comment: I forgot it. writing LaTeX on an iPad is a pain.

Comment: I certainly understand that, having answered many questions on my pathetic little 'droid!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have already obtained its solution by separation of variables. Perhaps needing to recognize special cases.

$ f_2 = 0 $ describes standard spring mass system of second order ODE including damping effect.The time curves are three types. Over-damped, critical damped and under / oscillatory damped.

Case $ f_1 = 0 $ is valid for motion in viscous medium where resistance is proportional to square of velocity. Speed reaches a terminal velocity when time $ \rightarrow \infty $. Examples are a steel ball coming down in an oil column (Stokes law), parachute drop speed stabilizing to a terminal velocity.The complex part is reducible to tanh function, quite a real physical phenomenon.

Even here for cases when $ f_1, f_2,f_3 $ are all present *real* steady state dynamic behavior also centers around critical damping case $ f_1/2 = \sqrt {f_0 f_2} $, $ c = \pi m. $

So draw curves in these three regimes  $ ( c > \pi m , = \pi m , > \pi m ) $ to distinguish among them.

Comment: The case where $f_2=0$ is actually very simple... $v(t) ={{\rm e}^{{\frac {f_{{
1}}t}{m}}}} \left( v_{{0}}+{\frac {f_{{0}}}{f_{{1}}}} \right)-{\frac {f_{{0}}}{f_{{1}}}}$, and has real solutions for all real $f_0$, $f_1$, where $f_1\ne 0$. As you observed, the case where $f_1/2=\sqrt{f_0 f_2}$, $c=\pi m$, but I am most concerned about the cases where ${f_1}^2>4f_0 f_2$, and the value returned by the square root operation is complex. I'm trying to write a computer program to do this, so some hard and fast rules on what I need to do to solve it is crucial to a workable solution for my purposes.

Comment: @Mark Have you got real plots using *proper* numerical values for the last case? .. just to make sure before hand that a real solution exists for which you are trying an analytical solution.

Comment: It appears that the last case can happen whenever the constant portion of the force being applied ($f_0$) is very small and there is significant drag being exerted on the object.  The velocity asymptotically approaches  0 quite quickly.. the faster it is moving initially, the steeper the slope.